# how to put a loop that asks user again and again to input till it enters correct country

Tags: python

how to put a loop that asks user again and again
to input till it enters correct country

```
population ={
    'china': '143',
    'india': '136',
    'usa': '32',
    'pakistan': '21'
}
population['bhutan'] = 2

print(population['china'])


country = input("enter countri name-")
country.lower()
if country in population:
    print(f"population {country} is: {population[country]} crore")
else:
   print("input again")
   country = input("enter countri name-")

if country in population:
    print(f"population {country} is: {population[country]} crore")
else:
   print("input again")
```

Comment: try a while loop? while country not in population: ...

Comment: You do not have loop at all. It seems like you may not be familiar with for and while loops in Python? Then I'd suggest looking for python tutorials on loops or more general questions about loops on stackoverflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do is with a while true that check if the input is correct using the break keyword that will stop the loop

```
while True:
   country = input("enter countri name-")
   if country in population:
        break;
```

Or even do something like this that is more pythonic

```
country = input("enter countri name-")
while country not in population:
   country = input("Enter valid country")
```